# Active Directory Domain Controller could not be contacted

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I am setting up an AD/DNS server for development purposes, but am having difficulty connecting to it from any client. The server is a vanilla Windows Server 2019 install on a public cloud computing enviromnent, setup following [this virtualgyanis guide](https://www.virtualgyanis.com/post/step-by-step-how-to-install-and-configure-domain-controller-on-windows-server-2019). The client is a Windows 10 box on our internal LAN.

The setup went smoothly but I can't get a client to connect to the DC. Any input would really be appreciated.

In Windows 10, when attempting to join the domain, I get the message "An Active Directory Domain Controller (AC DC) for the domain "simon.adtest" could not be contacted", with further information:

```
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.simon.adtest
The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
simondc2019.simon.adtest
However no domain controllers could be contacted.
```

It should be noted that the firewall has been disabled on both the server and client for troubleshooting. It also should be noted that this is not a production system and I would not normally advocate lowering the firewall.

Here is the ipconfig /all from the client:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SIMONMCALOO9364
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-4A-58-02
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.120(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 30 September 2021 12:05:31 pm
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 6 November 2157 9:03:20 pm
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 45.76.xx.xx (correct address of AD/DNS server confirmed)
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I am able to ping the AD (simon.adtest) and the server (SimonDC2019.simon.adtest):

```
Reply from 45.76.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=116
Reply from 45.76.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=116
Reply from 45.76.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=116
Reply from 45.76.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=116

Ping statistics for 45.76.xx.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms
```

nslookup is correctly resolving for both forward and reverse lookup zones:

```
Server:  SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx

Name:    simon.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx


C:\Users\simon>nslookup 45.76.xx.xx
Server:  SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx

Name:    SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx


C:\Users\simon>nslookup SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Server:  SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx

Name:    SimonDC2019.SIMON.adtest
Address:  45.76.xx.xx
```

In trying to troubleshoot I ran dcdiag on both the server and client. The server passed all tests with the only exception being:

```
    There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared. Failing SYSVOL
    replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.
    ......................... SIMONEVERYWHERE failed test DFSREvent
```

A different story on the client, with the following output:

```
Performing initial setup:
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SIMON
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... SIMON passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SIMON
      Starting test: Advertising
         Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (SIMON) call failed, error 1722
         The Locator could not find the server.
         ......................... SIMON failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... SIMON passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL
         replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.
         ......................... SIMON failed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         [SIMON] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 2,
         The system cannot find the file specified..
         The SysVol is not ready.  This can cause the DC to not advertise itself as a DC for netlogon after dcpromo.
         Also trouble with FRS SysVol replication can cause Group Policy problems.  Check the FRS event log on this DC.
         ......................... SIMON failed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... SIMON passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... SIMON passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         Could not open pipe with [SIMON]:failed with 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
         Could not get NetBIOSDomainName
         Failed can not test for HOST SPN
         Failed can not test for HOST SPN
         ......................... SIMON passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... SIMON passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         [SIMON] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 2,
         The system cannot find the file specified..
         ......................... SIMON failed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... SIMON passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... SIMON passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... SIMON passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... SIMON passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         ......................... SIMON passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... SIMON passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : SIMON
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... SIMON passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... SIMON passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : SIMON.adtest
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722
         A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(PDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722
         A Primary Domain Controller could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1722
         A Time Server could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error 1722
         A Good Time Server could not be located.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722
         A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.
         ......................... SIMON.adtest failed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... SIMON.adtest passed test Intersite
```

Error 1722 seems pretty ambiguous as it a general RPC failure. I have Googled and found a bunch of posts that don't apply to our setup for one reason or another, so i'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Check the registry ‘HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTFRS\Parameters\SysVol\DomainName’ on the domain controller. This key should not exist if SYSVOL replication is happening correctly on the domain controller and if the sysvol directory is published correctly. Also, if this key doesn’t exist means all potential source domain controllers in the domain should themselves have shared the NETLOGON and SYSVOL shares and applied default domain and domain controllers policy.

•   Please check for event 1704s in the application log of the domain controller as the ‘Enterprise Domain Controllers’ group should have the ‘Access this computer from the network’ right assigned in default domain controllers policy.

•   Also, please check the SYSVOL replica set under advanced features in ‘Active Directory Users and Computers’ under CN=’domain system volume’,CN=file replication service,CN=system,CN= as well as run the command ‘NTFRSUTL DS [DCNAME]’ on the domain controller. Output shows that the mentioned domain controller object is appearing in ‘CN=Domain System Volume(SYSVOL share),CN=NTFRS Subscriptions,CN=%DCNAME%,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=’. This will mostly resolve the issue of SYSVOL share not publishing and communicating with the client network.

•   Check the DFS replication state in the DCs in your domain by running the following command: -

```
  'For /f %i IN ('dsquery server -o rdn') do @echo %i && @wmic /node:"%i" 
     /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrreplicatedfolderinfo WHERE 
       replicatedfoldername='SYSVOL share' get 
      replicationgroupname,replicatedfoldername,state '
```

It will report the state of the SYSVOL share and the DFS service. Also, check the event logs for event ID 2213 for DFS replication service state.

Please check the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/recovering-missing-frs-objects-attributes-ad

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/force-authoritative-non-authoritative-synchronization